# libgdx tables don't resize

Tags: libgdx, scale

I create a screen menu using tables on libgdx, the game have 1920x1080p on phones with that resolution no problem, no problem on pc, but if the resolution is lower the table does not scale down, but every else is scaling down, the table is inside a stage, any ideas?

Here is the code on the create function

```
  tabela = new Table(skin);

        tabela.setBounds(0, 0,ObjetoJogo.EcraLargura, ObjetoJogo.EcraAltura);

    tabela.add(titulo);
    tabela.getCell(titulo).spaceBottom(100);//cria espao no fundo
    tabela.row();// para ficar um debaixo do outro
    tabela.padBottom(50);
    tabela.add(botaoJogar);
    tabela.getCell(botaoJogar).spaceBottom(65);//cria espao no fundo
    tabela.row();
    tabela.add(botaoSair);
    tabela.debug();
    stage.addActor(tabela);



ObjetoJogo.EcraLargura = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

ObjetoJogo.EcraAltura = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

On render function for render the table I have:

```
stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
```

any ideas?

Comment: What are `botaoJogar` and `botaoSair`?

Comment: According to Google translate that's Play Button and Exit Button, @Tenfour04.

Comment: set the table bounds to Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); and Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); on the resize method, the game could be creating the table with that bounds without the proper values, it all solves when you update everything that uses your screen width and height on the resize method.

Comment: The question is a bit to vague to know what's wrong and what you want. If you want a table to fill the screen, just call `setFillParent(true)` on it instead of trying to set its bounds manually. But all either of those steps do is set the maximum size of the table. You still have to tell its children to be bigger or its cells to expand to fill the space, depending on what you want it to look like.

Comment: You should translate your comments so others can help better

Answer (score 0):

I use setFillParent(true) didnt work botaoJogar and botaoSair are the Button images, the buttons are at the center of the screen